# ActiveModel::Serializers merge association attributes to root

Tags: json, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

Could not find hot merge AMS association attributes to the root JSON.

I have a Serializer:

```
class SomeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :object
end
```

And it renders `{ "object": { "field": "value" } }`. But I need to have just `{ "field": "value" }` response. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: this will be confusing, let the associations be *properly* described by serializer.

Comment: This is the bussines requirement, so I need to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like this. It will work

```
class SomeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :custom_field

  def custom_field 
    object.field
  end
end
```